# Electron pack error with electron-packager

Tags: ffmpeg, electron, pack

I've developed electron app with ffmepg and ffprob.
I use ffmpeg and ffprob with execFile and spawn function in main.js

```
const spawnProc = require('child_process').spawn
const execProc = require('child_process').execFile
const mpegPath = "ffmpeg.exe";
const probePath = "ffprobe.exe"
```

There was no problem when developing but after packing with electron-packager unexpected error occured.

Let me know how to solve this issue.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will answer your question but the simplest way I found to ensure compatibility across platforms with ffmpeg dependencies is to:

1. Use [ffbinaries](https://github.com/vot/ffbinaries-node) package and make it part of your build script. E.g. I use Webpack which compiles the frontend of my electron app onto a `dist/` folder, so I make it download the binaries onto `dist/bin`
2. Use [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) to consume the correct path to the ffmpeg dependencies bundled into your app. You can do it in such a way that uses an `.exe` extension if on Windows, etc.